# Test for 'ExceptionError' with py.test

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello I have an class object dice that eventually deletes itself.  Using py.test how can I make py.test return positive to the object deleting itself?

I tried this but it is a syntax error:

```
assert dice raises(ExceptionError)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pytest, test for expected errors like this

```
import pytest

with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
    1 / 0
```

that's an example from [the docs](http://pytest.org/latest/assert.html#assert), chapter *Assertions about expected exceptions*

In your case it would be something like this

```
import pytest

with pytest.raises(ExceptionError)
    # Instantiate a dice object
    # Do stuff that makes it delete itself
```

Here I used the error that you yourself named, I don't know if that is the actual error that is raised.

Answer (score 0):

You could check globals(). It contains all global variables.

```
if "dice" in globals():
    do something
else:
    raise(Exception)
```